# So, RStudio 2022.12.0 Build 353 does not show the last rows of the tibble in the R-document file. Anyone knows the solution, please

Tags: dataframe, tibble

so, I have this data in the tibble displayed in the R-document. The first rows are shown fine [the image of the first rows in the R-document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRKrK.png), but the last are not shown (its just empty tibble, which has the data, but these cannot be seen cause I like can copy some of them) [the image of the last rows in the R-document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tibqr.png). The same thing is happening if the data were in the dataframe. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue, so in the R-document, one can see all the data clearly? Thanks in advance.

I can look at the data with View(), no problem, but it is not the way I want the reader to see the data as it's like a different window and not in the R-Document. I expect these last rows be either non-present or show the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

ok, never mind. I just found a temporary and the best-at-the-moment solution, which is to use the function print.data.frame(). Though, it has not a good view like when you do it using the print() function, but it prints all the data ([first rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwr93.png)) ([last rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhJ9s.png)).